# Having a class with different method actions - Virtual or Delegate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an `Item` class in C# and I want to have two methods, `OnRightClick` and `OnLeftClick`, but I want every item to do different things upon using them (I am on Unity and this class is not a monoBehavior).

I heard about `virtual` methods, but from what I realized they can be overridden only from other classes that inherit them. However, I want to do without making a separate class for every item I make. How can I make those 2 methods vary?

I thought of using `delegate`, but it doesn't work the way I expected it to either. Is it even possible?

**EDIT**

(Ik the following line are not a thing but this is the best way I can somehow explain what I want to do)

Imagine having the following simple class Item

```
public class Item
{
    private string name;
    private float weight;
    private int price;
    private bool dropable;

    public Item(string name, float weight, int price, bool dropable)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
        this.dropable = dropable;
    }

    public Item(string name, float weight, int price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
        this.dropable = true;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public float GetWeight()
    {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public int GetPrice()
    {
        return this.price;
    }

    public bool GetDropable()
    {
        return this.dropable;
    }

    public void SetDropable(bool dropable)
    {
        this.dropable = dropable;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to make an OnRightClick and OnLeftClick that would vary from every item I create if I could do something like(As I said I know it's not valid but this is the best way I can explain it, also didn't mention it in the class above, this is the original class I currently have)

```
Item item1 = new Item(*all the stuff here*);
Item item2 = new Item(*other stuff*);
item1.OnRightClick = delegate {*what I want on right click*};
item1.OnRightClick(); //executes the function for item1
item2.OnRightClick = delegate {*other stuff on right click*};
item2.OnRightClick(); //executes a different function for item2
```

Again, this is not a valid code but I just used this to try and explain what I want to try and do, and to ask if there is any solutions to this that exist. In the worst case, if there aren't, I could just use virtual but I'd like that to be my last case of no choice.

Comment: i dont understand what you want, its unclear..i suggest you to write some lines of code to explain..

Comment: Methods belong to classes, which is where their implementation lies. What do you mean by *"making a separate class for every item I make"*? Typically you only need to write a single class to represent an object, and then create instances of the class for each "item". It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: as @Frenchy asked, these lines are not valid but explain the situation I'd like to get to (obviously by writing a valid and different code) but those are the results I'd like to get

Comment: @RufusL I meant by "*making a separate class for every item I make*" to not having to make an Item class then SomeItem : Item class then SomeOtherItem : Item class, but being able to put them all in one Item class

Comment: Tbh, if it was up to me, I'd make enums not classes, but C#'s enums are really bad in comparison to Java's enums... shame...

Comment: To have different implementations for a method implies different classes. You could include an implementation that does something different based on other property values of the class, though. Have you considered that already?

Comment: @RufusL you mean doing something like:

if (this.name = "item1")
{
//item 1 stuff
}
else if (this.name == "item2")
{
//item 2 stuff
}

Comment: Well, if `name` is the differentiator used to determine the behavior of the method, then I guess so. It would be helpful if you gave a concrete example of what you want. At some point in your code, you have to make a decision about what to do in the `OnRightClick` method. What *specifically* determines the behavior between different instances of the class?

Comment: The ideal solution is having OnRightClick and OnLeftClick to behave like virtual methods **without** the need to make a child class that inherits Item, but inside Item itself. I hope you can understand it because even to me it sounds a little unclear but it really is the best way I can explain that

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parent Item class then different children item classes that inherit from it the syntax it

```
public class MyItem : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum ItemType {HEALING, OFFENSIVE, CONSUMABLE, EQUIPMENT}
    public ItemType itemType;

    public float potency;

    public MyItem(ItemType _it, float _potency) {
    itemType = _it;
    potency = _potency;
    }

    public void OnRightClick() {
    switch (itemType) {
     case ItemType.HEALING:
     HealCharacter(character, potency);
     break;
     case ItemType.OFFENSIVE:

     break;

    // more cases
    }
    }
    public void OnLeftClick() {
    //fill in like onrightclick
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want it because if there's gonna be many items it's a lot of classes, I mean, if I don't have another choice I will do that, but I want to know if I can somehow story a method code as a class variable and execute it in a way that every class will have a different usage of the right and left click

Comment: just use overloaded constructor and switch statements then, i edited my answer

Comment: You can't have a public method that takes in a private type. The enum should be `public`. Also, the cases statements need to specify the enum, like: `case ItemType.HEALING:`

Answer (score 0):

You could use EventHandler:

in you class, you define:

```
    public event EventHandler RightClick;
    public void OnRightClick()
    {
        EventHandler handler = RightClick;
        if (null != handler) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

You use like that:

```
     // Enable Event
     RightClick += new EventHandler(OnRightClick);


     OnRightClick();

    public void OnRightClick(object s, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: This solution sounds nice however how well does it work if I have multiple items, It seems like that in this case I will have to make a lot of if statements to respond appropriately to which items have triggered the event. In this case, I rather already use Virtual, unless I am wrong(which I prob am because I never used listeners in C#), am I?

Comment: when you instaciate the class, you have an event linked to each class, so in the argument you could put what you want .. i dont see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action and Func to do what you are asking.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1

```
public enum ItemType
{
    Sword,
    Shield,
    Potion
}

public class Item
{
    private readonly Action leftClickHandler;
    private readonly Action<int> leftClickHandlerWithParam;
    private readonly Action rightClickHandler;
    private readonly Action<int> rightClickHandlerWithParam;

    public Item(ItemType itemType)
    {
        switch (itemType)
        {
            case ItemType.Potion:
                this.rightClickHandler = this.HandleClickWithFlash;
                this.leftClickHandler = this.HandleClickWithSound;

                this.leftClickHandlerWithParam = this.HandleClickWithFlash;
                this.rightClickHandlerWithParam = this.HandleClickWithSound;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void HandleLeftClick()
    {
        this.leftClickHandler();
    }

    public void HandleRightClick()
    {
        this.rightClickHandler();
    }

    private void HandleClickWithFlash()
    {
        // Logic here.
    }

    private void HandleClickWithFlash(int parameter)
    {
        // Logic here.
    }

    private void HandleClickWithSound()
    {
        // Logic here.
    }

    private void HandleClickWithSound(int parameter)
    {
        // Logic here.
    }
}
```

Here it is with the items exposed, if say you wanted a item factory concept.

```
public class ItemSettableHandlers
{
    public ItemSettableHandlers()
    {
    }

    public Action LeftClickHandler { get; set; }

    public Action RightClickHandler { get; set; }

    public void HandleLeftClick()
    {
        this.LeftClickHandler?.Invoke();
    }

    public void HandleRightClick()
    {
        this.RightClickHandler?.Invoke();
    }
}

public class ItemCreator
{
    public void CreateItems()
    {
        var itemSword = new ItemSettableHandlers();
        itemSword.LeftClickHandler = () =>
        {
            // Do sword left click here.
        };
        itemSword.RightClickHandler = () =>
        {
            // Do sword right click here.
        };

        var itemShield = new ItemSettableHandlers();
        itemShield.LeftClickHandler = () =>
        {
            // Do shield left click here.
        };
        itemShield.RightClickHandler = () =>
        {
            // Do shield right click here.
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not quite understand that solution, but I will look into it. Thank you

Comment: What are you not understanding? So I can explain more.

Comment: First, isn't Action a delegate? sorta...
and, is this solution dynamic, by that I mean. Can I have two different instances of a class, Item, for this example, to have two different actions on a click?

Comment: Yes action is a delegate. Updated answer with an example showing how to set it for each item instance.